# Android Navigation between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a form divided in few fragments. I call every fragment with:

```
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
if(fragment.equals(this.formOne) ||   fragment.equals(this.formTwo)) {
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

ft.replace(R.id.fragForm, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

When I click on the back button it skips the previous Fragment and goes back to the Activity but with a blank screen.

For example, I have 3 fragments : A - B - C

If I go to C and want to go back to the previous Activity, I click on the back button so I'm on B, I click again and I'm on A, and when I click again, I have a blank screen, I need to click another time to come back to the previous activity.

I don't understand why have I this blank screen on my Activity.

I don't understand this in the developer documentation:

> Note: You should not add transactions to the back stack when the
>   transaction is for horizontal navigation (such as when switching tabs)
>   or when modifying the content appearance (such as when adjusting
>   filters). For more information, about when Back navigation is
>   appropriate, see the Navigation design guide.

If we can't use that, what is the solution?

Answer (score 5):

Don't add it to the backstack when you add fragment A.

```
ft.add(R.id.fragForm, fragmentA);
ft.commit();


ft.replace(R.id.fragForm, fragmentB);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();

ft.replace(R.id.fragForm, fragmentC);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to Navigate to previous fragment don't add it to the backstack

Remove this

```
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

Comment: But i want to be able to come back at a previous fragment.

Comment: it's not running perfectly, because i have this "blank" screen at one moment :/

Comment: @Myste you have a ViewPager?

Comment: no, it's a form, and when the user "valid" (with a button) a part of my form, i call the next fragment, etc...

Comment: @M you also mention **If i go to the C fragment, and i want to come back at the previous activity**. So is it Activity or Fragment. Your post is very confusing

Comment: I have a activity, for exemple, "ActivityOne", with a button to go to the "ActivityTwo" In my "ActivityTwo" i have my fragments.

Comment: @Myste So what does this mean **If i go to the C fragment, and i want to come back at the previous activity**?? Form C back to previous activity ie ActivityOne. Pls make it cleat and also what has the note that you mention gotta do with the problem you are facing??

Comment: No, i want to mean, if the user is on the C Fragment, but he wants to come back to "ActivityOne", with what i did, when he clicks on the backbutton, he goes on the B Fragment, if he clicks again he is on the A fragment, but if he clicks again, he has a blank screen, not the "ActivityOne". He needs to click another time to have the ActivityONe. It's hard to explain. :/